# How to calculate (increment) padding from left to middle and from middle to right

Tags: javascript, math, react-native, slider, css-position

[image]

This is more math question but I think it's not for math section.
I render this boxes with numbers centered in it.
The whole width of the box is `350px`.
I have min and max number like `0-11` and I divide `350/11` to get each box width.
Bellow this I have a slider that is also `350px` width and thumb in it is `14px`.
What I want is that thumb position is always centered on number in a box above it.
**Problem**:
Middle number is fine it is always in center of the thumb, but as I go left or right number is not centered any more and more.
How I can calculate position for number inside box based on width values?

Comment: What is a / the "thumb"?

Comment: Thumb on the slider: https://articulate-heroes.s3.amazonaws.com/sliders5uz6pq0.png

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the position of the text inside each sub-box instead of scaling the box width itself?

Comment: I mean it's whatever to me I am trying just to center thumb and it's number. Like on this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGo3i.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the total box width from the slider parameters:

`box_width = (slider_width - slider_track_width) * num_sub_boxes / (num_sub_boxes - 1)`

In your case `box_width = 350px, num_sub_boxes = 11`. You can invert the formula if you want to set the slider width from a fixed box width instead:

`slider_width = (1 - 1 / num_sub_boxes) * box_width + slider_track_width`

Note that the slider thumb size has no relevance (I think anyway - let me know if I'm wrong).